# How to cache response in Asp.Net Core Middleware?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have created a Middleware in ASP.NET Core 3.1 to return a XML Sitemap from route `/sitemap.xml`.

```
public class SitemapMiddleware {

  private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

  public SitemapMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) {
    _next = next;
  }

  public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, ISitemapService sitemapService) {

  if (context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/sitemap.xml)) {

    Sitemap sitemap = sitemapService.GetSitemap();

    context.Response.ContentType = "application/xml";

    await context.Response.WriteAsync(sitemap.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);

  } else {

    await _next(context);
    
  }

}
```

And I register it as follows:

```
public static class SitemapMiddlewareExtensions {

  public static IApplicationBuilder UseSitemap(this IApplicationBuilder builder) {

    return builder.MapWhen(x => x.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/sitemap.xml"), 
      x => x.UseMiddleware<SitemapMiddleware>(route));

  } 

}
```

**Question**

How to cache the middleware's response and call the SitemapService only if the cached response has more than 24 hours?

Comment: inject cache service in the middleware and use it to cache the sitemap data as needed.

Comment: Or set cache header in response so server knows to cache response for desired time span

Comment: I suppose when you mention "CacheService" you mean `IMemoryCache memoryCache`. Which option would be better. The Cache Service to setting the Cache Header?

Comment: The easiest one is setting the response header, which passes control over to the server. Manually caching (in-memory, distributed,...etc) give more control to you if you have more complex scenarios to allow

Comment: In this case I am returning a sitemap with the website URLs to be accessed by Google and Bing. Because new URLS are only added once or twice a week I could easily return a cached version and only refresh it every 24 or 48 hours. Wouldn't this be more appropriate to use InMemory cache as I want to force that cache?